# Verb tense in sequences with "nachdem"

Tags: verb, conjunction

Well, [canoo.net](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Tempora/Zeitfolge.html?lang=en) explains verb tense sequence.

Nothing specific for *nachdem* is mentioned, but I remember from a German course that *nachdem* is different with respect to other temporal conjunctions. Can you help please?

Comment: The section with the title "Anteriority" deals with the word "nachdem". What is unclear?

Comment: unclear: nachdem is special or not ?

Comment: @orodeous I think you may remember _nachdem_ as a speacial case because it is basically the only (commonly used) temporal subjunction that necessarily indicates anteriority. So it does stand out in a sense as it, unlike other temporal subjunctions, ordinarily comes with a change of tense between main and subordinate clause.

Comment: @johnl This is the answer OP was looking for and you put it in a comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cite [the page you have linked](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Tempora/Zeitfolge.html?lang=en):

> *Unlike some other languages, German does not have strict rules for the sequence of tenses.*

That's true. Though that page lists some obvious examples in its *Anteriority* section which indeed **have** a tense sequence. But I show you a **counter example**:

> Ich sehe es mir an, nachdem ich hiermit fertig bin.
>
> Ich sah es mir an, nachdem ich damit fertig war.

This is both present/simple past tense. But the sequence of events is pretty much clear: first the completion of the current task, then looking at the new stuff.

Why is this possible? Because present tense is not only describing the present but also describing the **future** in German. And past tense does this, too, for narration. The sequence of events is put only by *nachdem*. Future, *nachdem* present.

So German does not impose a tense sequence on you. Not even with *nachdem*.